# Find and Move Files up One Level

Tags: unix, shell, solaris

I'm trying to search for files with a certain extension and then move all of them up one level in the folder hierarchy.

Basically I have something like

```
/path/to/application/files/and/stuff/a1/nolongerneededirectory/*.*
/path/to/application/files/and/stuff/a2/nolongerneededirectory/*.*
/path/to/application/files/and/stuff/a3/nolongerneededirectory/*.*
```

Im trying to move them up like this:

```
/path/to/application/files/and/stuff/a1/*.*
/path/to/application/files/and/stuff/a2/*.*
/path/to/application/files/and/stuff/a3/*.*
```

Ideally it would do something like:

```
-bash-3.2$ find /path/to/ -name '*.txt'
output:
/path/to/directories1/test1/test1.txt
/path/to/directories2/test2/test2.txt
/path/to/directories3/test3/test3.txt

then 
mv /path/to/directories1/test1/test1.txt /path/to/directories1/test1.txt
mv /path/to/directories2/test2/test2.txt /path/to/directories2/test2.txt
mv /path/to/directories3/test3/test3.txt /path/to/directories3/test3.txt
```

I've been playing with different options and asking around, anyone have any ideas?

EDIT 1:

So I tried

```
`find /path/to/parent/dir -type f -exec mv {} .. \
```

but I get a Permission Denied

Comment: well I tried this
`find /path/to/dir -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -i "$1" "${1%/*}"' sh {} \;`
but end up with this
`sh: bad substituion`

Comment: Yeah I'm not to sure, just starting to learn scripting in the last week, could elucidate that if you have a second?

Comment: I tried an option from what you linked above, but I get a different error assuming a different OS (Solaris 10 in my case).

`find test -type f -exec mv {} .. \;`
output
`mv: cannot rename test/test2/test3/test.jar to ../crap.jar: Permission denied`

Comment: Ah yes, I see the problem with this. So this will move the files relative to where I execute the command. What I'm actually trying to do is move the file up one level relative to the file. If that makes sense?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I read that wrong. The post I linked to will move the files to the parent directory from where you're starting. You want to move the files to *their own* parent directory. Deleted my comments as they are obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

If you have **GNU find**, you could do (modified from your example):

```
find /path/to -type f -execdir mv {} .. \;
```

but Solaris uses POSIX find as standard, which lacks this option. Sometimes the GNU tools are available (as e.g. `gfind`), though.

Also, the `-mindepth` switch would probably be very useful in this case to only return files at a given minimum directory depth.

---

**Without GNU find**, using a script instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS='
'
for i in $(find /path/to -type f); do
    echo mv -- "${i}" "${i%/*/*}"
done
```

This will work unless the file names contain newlines. Run it as above first, and remove the `echo` if it looks OK (also see the `-mindepth` remark above).

Comment: `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do` and `done < <(find /path/to -type f -print0)` will typically achieve the same, and it'd be completely safe, rather than `for i in $(find…)`.

Comment: OK, I just don't like to introduce Bashisms, but sometimes they do help. If someone wants to do the script like that, be sure to change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a script called `move_to_parent.sh`, make it executable.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -ge 1 ]
do
   parentPath=${1%/*/*};
   cp "$1" $parentPath;
   shift
done
```

Info on [parameter substitution found here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Here is another way of doing writing `move_to_parent.sh` using awk -

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -ge 1 ]
do
   echo $1 | awk -F/ '
             {
                parentPath="";

                for(loop=2;loop<NF-1;loop++)
                {
                   parentPath=parentPath"/"$loop;
                }
                sub(/\ /, "\ ", $0);
                system("mv " $0 " " parentPath );
             }'
   shift
done
```

Run as follows -

```
find /path/to/parent/dir -iname "*.txt" | xargs  /path/to/scripts/move_to_parent.sh
```

Comment: Or (untested, beware) `find /path/to/parent/dir -iname "*.txt" -exec /path/to/scripts/move_to_parent.sh '{}' '+'`

Comment: You sure this works with files with spaces or globbing characters in their name?

Comment: works fine with spaces